# Reading datagrid view coulmn values giving error at the end in c#

Tags: c#

I am reading the data grid view column values and than storing those values to database the values get add to database perfectly but at the end it give me an exception I really don't why its giving me an exception at the end .The exception is Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
here is my code .

```
for (int rows = 0; rows < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; rows++)
            {

                for (int col = 0; col < dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells.Count; col++)
                {
                    string value = dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells[col].Value.ToString();
                    MessageBox.Show(value);
                    string st3 = "INSERT INTO aprori_words(aprori) VALUES('" + value + "')";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(st3, con);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
            }
```

[image: exception snapshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most probable cause is `ToString()`, which throws an exception if `Value` is `null`.

`Convert.ToString()` returns an empty string for `null`, so try this instead:

```
var value = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells[col].Value);

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
{
    // call the rest of your code to save "value" to the database
}
```

You should also consider parameterizing your query. It'll be easier to maintain and more secure too.

```
var st3 = "INSERT INTO aprori_words(aprori) VALUES(@value)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(st3, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", value);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: but bro the problem occurs in loop the problem is not with database I have tried this without database it gave me the same error

Comment: The problem is not with database the problem is with for loop it give me the result I want but after excuting the last result it give me an exception .hope you understand what I want to convey

Comment: ok let me add some snapshot than you will be clear on my fault

Comment: please check the snapshot

Comment: yes I have replaced the code with your code but still its giving me the same exception

Comment: oops sorry I didn't replace the first line sorry

Comment: now I did replace the code with your code but still showing the same exception

Comment: you are great bro you made my day thanks a lot working perfectly was little error of mine and also I am too tired because its morning 4 15 am any how thanks alot